# modifying focus traversal in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtree, setfocus

I have a JTree that's working fine, with a mixture of leaf and non-leaf nodes. When I give the tree root focus, the down arrow and uparrow keys do the obvious thing. The small change I want to make is to have up/down arrow cause the focus to go to the next non-leaf node (ie skip over  leaf nodes). I can (I think) see how to do this by having the JPanel holding the tree respond to the up and down arrow keys, checking the nodes and moving accordingly, but this seems like it's reinventing the focus subsystem.

Is there an easier way, perhaps with a new focus traversal policy for the tree?

thanks

Comment: *"perhaps with a new focus traversal policy"* Perhaps.  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 4):

Neither the panel has anything to do with tree-internal navigation not is it focus-related. It's all handled via keyBindings in the tree's actionMap. So the solution is to replace the default navigational action by a custom action. The code snippet below does it by delegating to the default:

```
    final JXTree tree = new JXTree();
    tree.expandAll();
    final Action delegate = tree.getActionMap().get("selectNext");
    Action action = new AbstractAction("navigateNonLeaf") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean searching = true;
            while (searching) {
                TreePath old = tree.getLeadSelectionPath();
                delegate.actionPerformed(e);
                TreePath path = tree.getLeadSelectionPath();
                // nothing happened, back off
                if (areSame(old, path)) break;
                Object last = path.getLastPathComponent();
                if (!tree.getModel().isLeaf(last)) {
                    searching = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // TBD: implement "end of tree"
        private boolean areSame(TreePath old, TreePath path) {
            return path.equals(old);
        }
    };
    tree.getActionMap().put("selectNext", action);
```

Comment: Thanks! Excellent guidance; works beautifully for both selectNext and selectPrevious, with a minor tweak because there is one class of leaf nodes I did want it to visit, but that was easy to add to your example. Thanks again; saved me hours.

Comment: glad you found it helpful :-) You might consider to accept the answer, then